# Grouped list with sequential serial numbers across the groups in Nuxt 3 (Composition API)

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, grouping, vue-composition-api

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 project and trying to create a grouped table that displays team's information. I want to group the rows based on the "department" property and maintain sequential serial numbers across all groups. I'm using the Composition API to organize my component logic.

I have an array of objects as below:

```
const taskData = [
  {
    id: 55,
    tasks: 88,
    name: "Jim Gordan",
    dept: "Support",
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    tasks: 1,
    name: "Tiger Woods",
    dept: "DevOps",
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    tasks: 32,
    name: "Swim Philips",
    dept: "Support",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    tasks: 29,
    name: "Bill Doors",
    dept: "DevOps",
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    tasks: 120,
    name: "Michael Bay",
    dept: "Support",
  },
];
```

**Goal:**
I want to achieve the following output:
[image: Sample Output]

**Attempt:**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const sortedList = departmentData.sort((a, b) => (a.dept! < b.dept! ? -1 : b.dept! < a.dept! ? 1 : 0));
const deptBasedGroup = sortedList.reduce((groupedList: any, row) => {
   const currentGroup = groupedList[dept] ?? [];
   return { ...groupedList, [dept]: [...currentGroup, row] };
      }, {});
</script>
<template>
<div>
  <div class="title-bar">
      <div class="flex pr-10">
          <div class="title-row-text basis-1/6">No.</div>
          <div class="title-row-text basis-1/6">ID</h1>
          <div class="title-row-text basis-1/6">Tasks</h1>
          <div class="title-row-text basis-5/6">Name</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-for="(group, dept) in deptBasedGroup">
        <div class="single-row">
          <h1 class="stat-row-text basis-1/6"></h1>
          <h1 class="stat-row-text basis-1/6"></h1>
          <h1 class="stat-row-text basis-1/6"></h1>
          <h1 class="player-style-text basis-5/6">{{ dept }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in group">
          <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
          <div class="single-row">
            <h1 class="row-text basis-1/6">{{ index + 1 }}</h1>
            <h1 class="row-text basis-1/6">{{ item.id }}</h1>
            <h1 class="row-text basis-1/6">{{ item.tasks }}</h1>
            <h1 class="row-text basis-5/6 capitalize">{{ item.name }}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**Issue:**

While the grouping and the table structure seem to be working, I'm having trouble maintaining sequential "Serial No." values across all groups. Currently, the "Serial No." restarts from 1 for each group.

**Question:**

How can I modify my code to ensure that the "Serial No." values remain sequential across all groups while still achieving the desired grouped table structure? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!